# Notion API Return 404 "code":"object_not_found"

Tags: postman, http-status-code-404, fetch-api, notion-api, notion

Why my **Notion API return a 404 status**, even though i already **connect** my **Database** with my **Notion Integration**, where am i getting this wrong?

Here's my request via **Postman**:
[request to notion api using database_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQrve.jpg)

And here's my database id:
[database_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKYXR.png)

Database connected with my **Notion Integration**:
[database connected with my notion integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAt8S.png)

My **Notion Workspace** connected with my **Notion Integration**:
[workspace connected with my integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vIqD.png)

im hundred percent sure already providing the **correct bearer token from my integration on my request via postman**, why am i getting this error?

I've tried follow allong with the [Notion offical documentation](https://www.notion.so/help/add-and-manage-connections-with-the-api#add-connections-to-pages) guides but it just doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Dont believe everything you see on the internet"*, i just figured it out it's turn out that my **Database** is actually not a **Database** when you create **add a new page** in **notion** it doesn't mean that you're making a **new database**.

In order to **create a new database** in **Notion** you need to specified that **page** you just **added** to behave as a **database**, at the first place i thought when i **add a new page** in **Notion** it'll automatically to behave as a **database** as i follow along with some tutorial out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, it was a matter of adding the extension I created to the database.

By default, an extension does not have access to any database in your workspace you need to explicitly give that extension access to it.

If you see an ID then it is a database, pages have slugs this is what differentiates databases form pages.